# I can no longer run MS teams tab application in debug mode after teamsfx upgrade to version 5

Tags: microsoft-teams, teams-toolkit

I have an existing Teams Tab Javascript(react) application. It's been working fine in development and debug mode in Visual studio code.

I upgraded the teamsfx toolkit to version 5.2 from version 4.2, When i press F5 to run the application.

I get the following error message, when teams opens chrome browser to load the app.

```
This app cannot be found.
```

The App is registered in the Azure portal. What am i missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you have completed the necessary setup and configuration steps after upgrading to Teams Toolkit version 5.2. Check if there are any specific migration steps mentioned in the documentation for upgrading from version 4.2 to version 5.2.
Verify that the app registration in the Azure portal is correct. Ensure that the app registration details, such as the client ID and redirect URI, are accurate and match the configuration in your application code.
Check if the app is properly configured for sideloading in Teams. In the Azure portal, navigate to the app registration for your Teams Tab application and go to the "Teams" section. Make sure that the "Allow sideloading of external apps" option is enabled.

Comment: Hello AfDev - If you have updated TeamsFx to the latest version. Please check if your later version is compatible or supported with Teams toolkit version. Please try to update toolkit version as well and check it once. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/toolkit/toolkit-v4/teamsfx-collaboration-v4